# Oracle - Trigger to check constraint before insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

i would like to create a simple trigger to check a stored variable from a table.
if the value of the variable is '1', then approve the insertion 
else if the value of the variable is '2', then prompt error message.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER approval 
BEFORE INSERT ON VIP
REFERENCING OLD AS MEMBER
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  CONDITION_CHECK NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT CONDITION INTO CONDITION_CHECK FROM MEMBER; 
  IF CONDITION_CHECK = '2' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, ' UPGRADE DENIED!');
  END IF;
END;
```

But this trigger disable all the entries even when the condition value is '1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AFTER` triggers to check conditions: the values can be modified by other `BEFORE` triggers. In `AFTER` triggers, you are guaranteed that the value won't be changed afterwards.

It seems you're missing a condition in your `SELECT` (if as I believe you're trying to get the value from another table):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER approval 
AFTER INSERT ON VIP
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  CONDITION_CHECK NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT CONDITION 
    INTO CONDITION_CHECK 
    FROM MEMBER 
   WHERE member_id = :new.member_id; 
  IF CONDITION_CHECK = '2' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'UPGRADE DENIED!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply reference the `:new.condition` in your trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER approval 
  BEFORE INSERT ON VIP
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.condition = '2' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, ' UPGRADE DENIED!');
  END IF;
END;
```

It would, however, make little sense to put this sort of logic into a trigger.  It would make far more sense to define a `CHECK` constraint on the column that ensures that the `condition` is one of an allowed set of values.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the old data rather than the new - presumably that's not what you intended?

Comment: Did you mean for this to be an answer? If so, you may want to make it look... more like an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I believe it is an answer, sufficient at least to tell him what the problem is - I don't feel I need to hold hands.